# Грамматическая основа предложения "О русском языке писалось много"

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая грамматическая основа в предложении "О русском языке писалось много".

Вызывает сомнение роль слова "много", потому что, если добавить "много книг", это явно будет подлежащее.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это безличное предложение с грамматической основой "писалось"

Answer (score 1):

МНОГО является обстоятельством, выраженным наречием, при сказуемом ПИСАЛОСЬ. Ср.: писалось часто.

Answer (score 1):

МНОГО является обстоятельством, выраженным наречием, при сказуемом ПИСАЛОСЬ. Ср.: писалось часто.

Comment: Виноградов В. В., Гвоздев А. Н., Розенталь Д. Э. относят к числительным такие слова, как много, мало, немного, столько, сколько, несколько и др. Некоторые,действительно, относят "много" к наречию. Но в предложении  оно выступает в качестве определительного наречия ( указывает на степень количества), отвечая на вопросы: сколько,на сколько?; в какой степени?

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном вами предложении, грамматической основой является "писалось". Слово "много" здесь является числительным в роли определения. Вы путаете слово "многое", которое является существительным и может выступать в роли подлежащего.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь сказуемое "писалось" в безличном предложении.

Морфология: Слово "много" является наречием или неопределенно-количественным числительным.

Синтаксис: В предложении "много" может быть:

1) Наречием в роли обстоятельства: Писалось много.

2) В функции сказуемого: Денег много не бывает. Этого мне слишком много.

3) Подлежащим: Много не мало.

4) Подлежащим в составе счетного оборота: Об этом написано много книг.